# Ubuntu 20.04 hangs when Wi-fi gets connected

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 installation that was working fine for some months. Today morning everything was okay, but now, when I turn on my laptop and connect to the Wi-Fi, it suddenly freezes completely and I cannot do a single thing. From mouse to keyboard, everything gets stuck.

Now I am using mobile tethering and the internet is working fine, which shows that it is some driver issue. These are my wireless adapter's drivers:

[image: wireless adapter drivers]

Any solution or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't use the alternative driver for this network adapter. I set "do not use the device", and use kernel driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got my laptop back to normal. These are some of the random steps I followed.

1. Turn on LivePatch
2. Update the Ubuntu
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. Updated the headers `sudo apt-get install --reinstall git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
5. Reboot `sudo reboot`

Now wi-fi is working normal and laptop is not getting stuck.